# Interactive Display of reflectivity data for PPI in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, cartopy

As a part of our project, we need to display radar reflectivity data in Plan Position Indicator(PPI) image along with latitude and longitude.  I am using plot_ppi_map function to Plot a PPI volume sweep on geographic map.  A sample output of my program is given below

[Sample output of the Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4VnP.png)

I am able to get latitude and longitude values in the bottom left corner of status bar, but not able to display values of radar reflectivites. Generated radar reflectivity values from following code

```
display = pyart.graph.RadarMapDisplay(radar)

rfdata = display._get_data(field = 'reflectivity', sweep = 0,mask_tuple = None,filter_transitions = True,gatefilter=None)
```

Tried using [Example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html) mentioned and tried working with ax.format_coord() with reflectivity data derived from display._get_data and got reflectivity data of size (361,1000). But getting Index error as mentioned below(screenshot also enclosed)

IndexError: index 176327 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 361

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVwmp.png)

I am using the following code snippet to plot reflectivity data on a map.
Projection that I am using in this is AzimuthalEquidistant

```
    class Formatter(object):
        def __init__(self, im):
            self.im = im
        def __call__(self, x, y):
            z = self.im.get_array()[int(y), int(x)]
            return 'x={:.01f}, y={:.01f}, z={:.01f}'.format(x, y, z)  

    projection = ccrs.AzimuthalEquidistant(central_latitude=radar.latitude['data'][0],central_longitude=radar.longitude['data'][0])

    display.plot_ppi_map('reflectivity', 0, vmin=-31.5, vmax=95.5,
                             min_lon=min_longitude, max_lon=max_longitude, min_lat=min_latitude, max_lat=max_latitude,
                             lon_lines=np.arange(77, 85, 1), resolution='110m',shapefile = shapefile_path,ax=ax,
                             shapefile_kwargs = {'linewidth':1, 'edgecolor':'black', 'facecolor':"#00000000"},
                             cmap = dwrmpt,norm=norm, embelish = False,
                             lat_lines=np.arange(12, 20, 1), projection=projection,
                             fig=fig, lat_0=radar.latitude['data'][0],
                             lon_0=radar.longitude['data'][0])
im = ax.imshow(rfdata, interpolation='none')
ax.format_coord = Formatter(im)
plt.show()
```

I am expected to display reflectivity data whenever data is available.

I need to display reflectivity values along with latitude and longitude. Please advise.

Comment: Provide more information. like the code and inputs.

Comment: @Andy_101: Thanks a lot for your response. I am using plot_ppi_map fuction. I have edited my post with necessary inputs